# Python not recognizing PhantomJS from Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, phantomjs, nameerror

I'm starting to learn about web-scraping and so I'm trying to use PhantomJS in Python. After a few hours of getting past the ghostdriver.log barrier I'm now hitting my head against a NameError: global name 'PhantomJS' is not defined

I'm working on a Windows 10 machine, I've got phantomjs 2.1.1, and metaperl::selenium 2.40.0 (and is this different than selenium?)

Here's my code:

```
import selenium as sel  #i don't think this was needed, but i was trying anything
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='~/Downloads/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/bin')
driver.set_window_size(1024, 768) 
driver.get('https://www.google.com/#q=data+science')
```

Full exception message:

```
NameErrorTraceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-21-f352fd375d8b> in <module>()
4 from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
5 
----> 6 driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='~/Downloads/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/bin')
7 driver.set_window_size(1024, 768)
8 driver.get('https://www.google.com/#q=data+science')

C:\Users\Elizabeth\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\phantomjs\webdriver.pyc in __init__(self, executable_path, port, desired_capabilities, service_args, service_log_path)
47         """
48         self.service = Service(executable_path, port=port,
---> 49             service_args=service_args, log_path=service_log_path)
50         self.service.start()
51 

C:\Users\Elizabeth\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\phantomjs\service.py in __init__(self, executable_path, port, service_args, log_path)
37          - log_path: Path for PhantomJS service to log to
38         """  
---> 39         PhantomJS(service_log_path=os.path.devnull)
40         self.port = port
41         self.path = executable_path

NameError: global name 'PhantomJS' is not defined
```

I've tried playing with the path name, setting the executable path outside of that code, read documentation for selenium and phantomjs, and searched the web for hours for anything else I could figure out about what's going on with it.

Comment: You'd better add the whole exception message.Fill full `phantomjs.exe` path works for me,  such as `driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='C:/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/bin/phantomjs.exe')` .

Comment: It looks like selenium installed in `Anaconda2` has some errors.I don't have `Anaconda2` environment.You can try reinstall newest `selenium` or use official python and `pip install selenium` to determine if it is environment problem.

Comment: This is a brand new install, but I guess reinstalling couldn't be the worst thing.

Comment: i'm afraid it had no change